# How to allow arbitrary query string with url alias?

Tags: 7, uri

Using Google Custom Search and as part of it's configuration I specify a callback url on my site (e.g., www.example.com/search).  I setup my page www.example.com/search as a Basic Page.

When someone searches for something they are taken to the url I specify and arbitrary query string parameters are appended (e.g., www.example.com/search?cx=partner&ie=UTF-8&q=dom&sa=Search&siteurl=www.example.com/search).

However this results in a page not found because Drupal appears to treat the entire request path as a url alias which it can't find.

How can I allow arbitrary query strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drupal doesn't treat the query string as part of the URL alias, the problem is that your URL has the `q` parameter as part of it (`q=dom`).

Google obviously uses that for some purpose, but Drupal uses `$_GET['q']` to determine the path of the page that should be shown. So when you visit a URL with `q=dom` in the query string, Drupal will try to find a page with the path `dom`...which obviously doesn't exist on your server.

Short of some crazy hacking of Drupal core (and probably dozens of contrib modules) I think the only way you're going to solve this is by somehow changing the original query string and removing the `q` parameter from it.

Comment: Thankfully Google's Custom Search Element Control API v2 has support for changing the query string parameter.

Comment: Core has an outstanding issue for this:
Url Alias with Query String (D7) [#225112],  https://www.drupal.org/node/225112#comment-11917892